# Factory pattern with static registration

Tags: c#, factory, static-constructor

I'm having a problem when trying to register my types using their static constructors, with the following factory:

```
 public class Factory<T>
{
    public static Factory<T> Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private static Factory<T> _instance = new Factory<T>();
    private Factory() { }
    static Factory() { }

    static Dictionary<string, Type> _registeredType = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public void Register(string id, T obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType().IsAbstract || obj.GetType().IsInterface)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot create instance of interface or abstract class");

        _registeredType.Add(id, obj.GetType());
    }

    public T Create(string id, params object[] parameters)
    {
        Type type;

        if(!_registeredType.TryGetValue(id, out type))
            throw new UnsupportedShapeException(id);

        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
    }
}
```

Then if I use a static constructor for registration it doesn't work:

```
    public interface IShape
{
    string print { get; }
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
    static Circle()
    {
        Factory<IShape>.Instance.Register("Circle", new Circle());
    }

    public string print
    {
        get
        {
            return "Circle";
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? The factory appears to set up fine but I just can't get the ctor to work. Cheers.

Comment: An static cosntructor is executed the first time some code access to a class, are you accessing that class in somewhere?

Comment: Please be more specific about how it is not working.

Comment: Sorry I should've been clearer, I'm trying to implement this:http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Comment: In the code above your Factory would have to be declared a static member of circle and the constructor removed.

Comment: I should have been more specific. If I take this code and compile it (there are a couple of compiler errors that need to be fixed as well), it doesn't do anything. So you must have 1) some additional code that is not shown, 2) some expectations of what that code's output should be, and 3) the actual output (which is different). Please add that information.

Comment: I haven't actually referenced the concrete classes anywhere.. wow my bad! Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

It's not an answer but an advice. First, when you use generic class actually CLR creates class for every implementation. This classes will have different static variables and you can not use one factory for all classes. The good news is that you can use generic methods instead of generic class. And you even do not need to create an instance of `T` object:

```
public class Factory
{
    public static Factory Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private static Factory _instance = new Factory();
    private Factory() { }

    static Dictionary<string, Type> _registeredType = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public void Register<T>(string id)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (type.IsAbstract || type.IsInterface)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot create instance of interface or abstract class");

        _registeredType.Add(id, type);
    }

    public T Create<T>(string id, params object[] parameters)
    {
        Type type;

        if(!_registeredType.TryGetValue(id, out type))
            throw new UnsupportedShapeException(id);

        return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Factory` to register and resolve objects:

```
Factory.Instance.Register<Circle>("Circle");
var firstCircle = Factory.Instance.Create<Circle>("Circle");
var secondCircle = Factory.Instance.Create<IShape>("Circle");
```

Comment: This is good, but given the OP's pattern, I would think that `Create` should return `object` instead of `T` and not be generic, so that the string `id` is clear in being the only determination of the output type. It also avoids the factory being the location of any improper casting when the types aren't compatible and an exception is thrown (the generic is just a casting hint). This leads to code that (to me) is much clearer about what's going on: `var firstCircle = (Circle) Factory.Instance.Create("Circle");
var secondCircle = (IShape) Factory.Instance.Create("Circle");`

Comment: @ErikE actually we can compare types from dictionary and generic parameter in Create method and if type is not implements/inherits T throw a custom exception that will show the real problem. But it's the same but little bit "strongly-typed" to use generic parameters and cast result inside the factory. IMHO. And string is just a string. Is there a reason in author's scenario to register types by string identifier or he can just use generic wrapper for Activator.CreateInstance?

Comment: @Vadim I like this! For the scenario I was using I do require an ID to be used but I think your implementation could be very effective without it so like you said the generic type would be the only id it needed. So.. Factory.Instance.Create<Circle>();

Comment: In a simplest scenario with `Factory.Instance.Create<Circle>();` for concrete classes it can be just a wrapper: 
`public T Create<T>(params object[] parameters)
{
    return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameters);
}`

Comment: If he's creating types by string then the string alone should work. Having to also specify a type defeats the whole scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I know what you are going after, however, it would probably be best to make controller'esqe classes that contain your factory instantiation. However, constructor injection will not work on static classes or descendants.

```
public static class StaticFactoryClassController
{
    private static readonly IStaticFactoryService service=AppServiceFactory.Instance.Create<IStaticFactoryService>();

    public static void DoSomething() 
    {
        Service srv = new StaticFactoryClassService(service);
        srv.DoSomething(); 
    }
}
```

And with that you could create a service class--

```
public class StaticFactoryClassService
{
    private readonly IStaticFactoryService service;

    public StaticFactoryClassService(IStaticFactoryService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
       this.service.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

And finally your binding interface--

```
public interface IStaticFactoryService
{
    DoSomething();
}
```