# Factory pattern where concrete classes are on separate DLLs

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I wrote a dlls that connect to some 3rd party API, each DLL has the methods: `SignIn`,`Upload`,`Download`,`SignOut`.

My manager asked me to implement a factory pattern because in future I will write more dlls to other APIs that has the same methods signuture.

For now I have:

**DLL 1: OneDrive**

It has a class with methods: `SignIn`,`Upload`,`Download`,`SignOut`.

So if I want to use it I'm adding reference to this DLL and then any app can use this DLL.

**DLL 2: DropBox**

It has also class with methods: `SignIn`,`Upload`,`Download`,`SignOut`.

> My question: How do I implement the factory method design pattern in this secnario?

What I did: I created another DLL("The new DLL") this DLL would contain the "FactoryClass", the problem is that the creator in this dll should return a type of "OneDrive" or "DropBox" that means I should add refernce to the first two dlls ("OneDrive" and "DropBox").

But, The classes "OneDrive" and "DropBox" should implement some abstrct class whithin the new dll that means I should add refernce to the new dll.

but it's not possible because it's circular dependency (Visual studio error)

Comment: You need 1) a dll which provides the interface / base class that both of your classes should implement, and 2) your dll which contains the factory, and all of your other code.

Comment: I am agree with @canton7 You will have 2 concrete object which inherited an interface by the methods. You will inject this concrets to your factory

Comment: I think a factory won't be enough. Sounds more like you need some sort of "Plug-In" System. For example: You might want to detect implementors of that interface automagically and provide them in a Config-Dialog ...

Comment: @Fildor I don't think dynamic loading of dlls / discovery of implementations is necessary at all. There's no call for that level of complexity. The factory means that you can introduce that later if you need to, but don't do it unless it's actually needed.

Comment: @canton7 How do you know? As the question is written and describes the architecture, it sounds exactly like a PlugIn System. AutoDetection is not mandatory of course. It was just an example of what you can do if you have one. I for one would want to automate things as much as possible and not be forced to touch additional code if new implementations are added.

Comment: @Fildor because he hasn't mentioned any requirements for a plugin system: the question is purely about which dlls reference which. Code which does `if (...) { return new OneDriveApi(); } else if (...) { return new DropboxApi(); }` is much simpler and easier to understand and maintain than something which automatically searched for implementations, and uses some rules to decide which to use. Sure there are advantages to doing this, but it does come at a cost. You need to make that judgement call. In this case, he's struggling with the simple stuff, so keep it simple.

Comment: @canton7 I think you misunderstood my intentions. Having been in his shoes, I can see where it is going. So I just wanted to hint towards considering if it is worth thinking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to eliminate the circular dependencies, you must keep the dependencies in the direction of your main assembly.

This is in partly solved by an interface (or abstract class) declared in this central assembly, but there is the additional problem of instantiating the concrete implementations without directly referencing the dependencies.

This can be solved by allowing your factory to keep a registry of available implementations. You can find an example of [a simple factory with registration in this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730466/factory-pattern-with-static-registration)